# iFrame Not Loading IE 8

Tags: html, css, iframe, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

My website seems to work in all browsers but IE 8. Everything loads fine by the iFrame.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<head>
   <title> Title </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="respond.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="http://instagram.com/p/cR5BORA8Ij/embed/" 
            width="300" height="400" frameborder="0" 
            scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" id="myFrame"></iframe>      
</body>
```

Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: are you using a proper doctype? Are there console errors?

Answer (score 1):

## Here's a full breakdown:

### Steps to Reproduce:

Create a page that has `position:relative` on the `html` element

```html
<html style="position:relative">
    <head></head>
    <body>TEST</body>
</html>
```

Here's a test page in fiddle that does just that:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/DZbt5/show/light

Now use that page inside of an iFrame and open in IE8

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/DZbt5/show/light/"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### [Here's a fiddle that should work in all browsers *EXCEPT* IE8](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/uqDUL/7/show/light)

### Solution:

As the previous answer suggests, you can remove `position:relative` from the original html page, but you might not have access to the page or be able to change it.

Instead, you can simply add relative position to the `iframe` element itself:

```css
iframe {
    position: relative;
}
```

#### [Working Demo in Fiddle - Also works in IE8](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/uqDUL/8/show/light)

### Other Instances

Question was also asked here:

- [iFrame content doesn't show in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11191155/1366033)
- [Blank iFrame in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4444014/1366033)

Comment: Sometimes, iframe contains page information but it get squeezed. In that case, iframe should have min-height, min-width value to encounter that problem

Answer (score 0):

From the question [iFrame content doesn't show in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191155/iframe-content-doesnt-show-in-ie8):

Just remove the following rule from the iframed content:

```
html { position: relative; }
```