# Open PDF blob with IE (using object URL)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, pdf

I have an iframe where I would like to display a pdf. I got it to work with chrome and FF but not with IE. Here is how I do it:

```
<iframe src="+ URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob) +"></iframe>
```

What's wrong with IE and how can I fix that? I don't get any error (I'm using IE 11)...

Comment: Did u find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @sdd I think IE doesn't allow to do this for securtity reasons (but I can be wrong, it's so long I can't exactly remember my conclusion)...anyway I gave up on iframe

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a height and width?
`<iframe src="+ URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob) +" width="960px" height="900px"></iframe>`

**

or have you had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191155/iframe-content-doesnt-show-in-ie8) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444014/blank-iframe-in-ie)?

```
css/some.css
iframe {
    position: relative;
}
```

might help.

i can't really think of how it could be problem with the src, since you indicate that it works in other browsers. so it's probably about how the wonderful ie is 'displaying' an iframe.

Comment: Height and width are set up properly.. I didn't write it here to make it simpler. BTW it's working on Chrome and FF

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? i am running into the same problem